# Laravel 5 - Eloquent belongsToMany query issue

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm kinda newbie dealing with laravel, and I got stuck into something

I have this scenario and I'm strugling to get the correct relationship for that, and I hope someone could show me some enlighting thoughts :)

I've these two models: Order and User. I have two types of users. Clients and professionals. 
When a client places an order, it is assigned to 5 professionals.

I created a pivot table 'order_user', to deal with the selected professionals for each order.

Oh, I can't split users into clients and professionals, because a professional can also act as a client, and order services from other types of professionals.

These are the pieces of relationship code I thought I would be adding to the two models (probably not working at all)

on my User model:

The client user orders

```
public function orders(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Orders');
}
```

The professional user assigned orders

```
public function assigned_orders(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'order_user', 'order_id', 'user_id');
}
```

on my Order model:

The order creator user

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

The users assigned to that order

```
public function assigned_users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'order_user', 'order_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Does this make any sense?

How could I, as a professional, retrieve, the orders which I'm assigned to?

And if there's other points to change, let me know

Thank u all in advace!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your setup some --

In your User model:

```
public function orders(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'order_user', 'order_id', 'user_id');
}
```

In your Order model:

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'order_user', 'order_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Then all you need to do to retrieve "your" assigned Orders is:

```
$my_orders = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->orders;
```

And if you want to keep the "owner" concept, in your Order model:

```
public function owner(){
    // references owner_id
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer Samsquanch, but it is still not working... :(

When I'm a client retrieving the orders I placed, I can retrieve it all easily.

Just to clarify: the user_id from the client who placed the order, is stored as an attribute user_id, on the Order model. 

The only user data stored on the pivot table order_user, are the ids from the professionals, assigned to the orders.

These are ones I'm still having trouble to retrieve...It is still giving me an empty array, although the order_user table is filled correctly...


But thanks anyway for the support :)

Comment: Wow, I could retrieve the data changing the the assigned_orders function from the user model:

    public function assigned_orders(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order');
    }

just got rid of the pivot table information on it...  Probably a silly newbie question, but why it blocking me from getting the data?

Thanks again!